# How to align text with easy way?

Tags: excel, notepad++

I have a `CSV` file containing thousands of rows. Each line is `delimited by a semi-colon(;)`, `starting with character <--` and `ending with character -->`. For example like this:

```
<--;2016;computer printer scaner;
Computer hardwares;-->
<--;2015;computer printer
scaner;Computer hardwares;-->
<--;2014;computer 
printer
scaner;Computer hardwares;-->
```

I want to edit it so it looks like this:

```
<--;2016;computer printer scaner;Computer hardwares;-->
<--;2015;computer printer scaner;Computer hardwares;-->
<--;2014;computer printer scaner;Computer hardwares;-->
```

Usually I do it manually one by one as many as thousands of lines. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done in 1 pass, using [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

This will replace all linebreaks that is not after the string `-->`

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!-->)\R`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!-->)  : negative lookbehind, make sure we don't have "-->"
\R        : any kind of line break
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<--;2016;computer printer scaner;Computer hardwares;-->
<--;2015;computer printerscaner;Computer hardwares;-->
<--;2014;computer printerscaner;Computer hardwares;-->
```

Answer (score 1):

in notepad++

1. go to find and replace.
   find all instances of \r and \n and replace with nothing (make sure search mode is set to extended)
2. find --> and replace with -->\n

that should display as your example